# Where do you find your player ID

Tags: pokemon-go

I have forgotten my password and I'm still logged in to Pokèmon Go. I just don't want to take the risk not knowing my player ID, if I might accidentally sign out. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 4):

It's in your settings tab below the Sign Out button.
You can also see, if it's a google account.

[image: PoGoScreen]